# To use hr tag between sections?

Tags: html

```
<section .../>
<hr/>
<section .../>
<hr/>
<section .../>
```

Is it a semantic way to use the hr tag in this way?

in MDN said

"The HTML hr element represents a thematic break between paragraph-level elements (for example, a change of scene in a story, or a shift of topic with a section);"

section is not a paragraph-level elements??

Comment: Yes it is semantically correct. A `section` qualifies as a "paragraph-level element".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [offical HTML specification about `<hr>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element):

> There is no need for an `hr` element between the sections themselves, since the `section` elements and the `h1` elements imply thematic changes themselves.

So no, you don't need an `<hr>` between sections because of semantics as that is already implied by the use of sections. If you want to *style* it like there was a separator between sections, you can just specify a border color on the sections themselves.